# Read/Write permission for SharePoint list in Access 2013

Tags: permissions, office-web-apps, microsoft-access

I have been using Access web Apps for some time but now need to move to SharePoint list. I have all lists in place and have created new Access DB to sync with the list imported from the Azure database.

The tables imported to Access fine but are read only - my Office 365 user level is full as I am admin. Where is setting for table read/write?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Settings-> Advanced Permissions-> Settings-> Permission levels.

This should take you to http://server/sites/sitename/_layouts/role.aspx page.

Here you can able to see the default permission levels.

Since you are saying that you want a contribute permission without delete, click on the default Contribute Permission displayed here.

In the end of the page, click Copy Permission Level button.

In the page opened give your custom permission level name and under List Permissions just uncheck the Delete Items permission. (this copies all permissions of Contribute and removes delete permission)
Now click ok and your custom permission level is created.

While creating a group or assigning permission to the user, use this custom level permission instead of contribute.

Also please try: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB